# Laravel Notification multiple users with pusherjs

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications, pusher

What I'm doing in sending a `Notification` to multiple users with Laravel Facade

```
Notification::send($users, new PartenaireSendCRNotification($data));
```

This is the PartenaireSendCRNotification class:

```
// I need the Database and Broadcast on Pusher channel
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database', 'broadcast'];
}

// Name of the Pusher channel
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ["new-cr-from-part"];
}

// Send data
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->data
    ];
}
```

On the Front End (blade and js):

```
 @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin || Auth::user()->isConfirmation)
     <script>
         // ... some pusher configuration

         // subscribe to the channel 'new-cr-from-part'
         let channel = pusher.subscribe('new-cr-from-part');

         // listen for event BroadcastNotificationCreated
         channel.bind(
            'Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated', 
            function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 // Some javascript 
                 receiveCRNotification();
         });

     </script>
@endif
```

Only **6 users** match the condition to execute the script for listening to the channel.

When I test it, every thing works fine (I have 6 notifications in the Database) but the js after the binding to the channel is executed 6 times for every user.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Not enough code, but I'd guess Notification::send($users, new PartenaireSendCRNotification($data)); is called 6 times while the $users array sends a notification to each user causing the 6*6 notifications

Comment: I think it's a problem with public and private channels. I know that Laravel can't broadcast a Notification on a **private channel**. It's why I'm binding the all Namespace for the channel listener. So the 6 Notifications are Broadcasted for all the 6 Users but in the database i have a correct number of notifications.